# How do you accomplish the following sequence with a nested list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

How would i create a nested loop list comprehension with the following sequence in python3?

I want to accomplish this

```
for x in range(2):
    for y in range(2):
        print((x,y))
    print("hi")
```

(0, 0)
(0, 1)
hi
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
hi

But, I could only get this far ...

```
[ print((x,y))
    for x in range(2)
    for y in range(2)
]
```

(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehensions are not replacements for normal `for` loops. It is also not the best practice to use functions with side effects (such as `print`) inside them. That being said, this is a (rather convoluted) way to implement what you are after:

```
>>> print([y if y == "hi" else (x, y) for x in range(2) for y in list(range(2)) + ["hi"]])
[(0, 0), (0, 1), 'hi', (1, 0), (1, 1), 'hi']
```

Or, if you insist having the `print` inside the comprehension:

```
[print(y if y == "hi" else (x, y), end=" ") for x in range(2) for y in list(range(2)) + ["hi"]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!!! I am trying to may ascii art with list comprehensions! =). It really is convoluted. But those are the constraints.

Comment: That was your trick >>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> a + [5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]